# Python Pandas Join doesnt work unexpected argument

Tags: python, pandas, join

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("sdvsdvsvsd.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv("dsvsdvdv.csv")

df3 = df1.join(df2, how='inner', left_on = 'TIME', right_on = 'TIME')
```

I created a joint but when I run it, I get a message"unexpected argument". I checked it multiple times and cant see any misstake.

beginner here, please help

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.join` doesn't have arguments `left_on` or `right_on`, just `on`. Are you mistaking it for `pandas.DataFrame.merge` ?

Comment: Try this: 'pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner, left_on ='TIME', right_on = 'TIME) Edit: Drat, foiled by 19s

Comment: when i remove left_on and right_on and instead use on="Time" i get an error message.raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'TIME'     ...... When i use pd.Merge i also get the same error message when i only use on="Time"

Comment: what you mean by share your dataframe?

Comment: It sounds like at least one of your dataframes does not have `'TIME'` for a column. Please share what your dataframes look like in the question so we can try and replicate the issue.

Comment: maybe you want merge function: df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on = 'TIME', right_on = 'TIME')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner, left_on ='TIME', right_on = 'TIME')` instead.

`.join` doesn't have `left_on` or `right_on`

Comment: when i do it the way you wrote it i get the following message: " raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'TIME'"

Comment: Can you send a sample of your csv files? Or just the column names.

Comment: The column name is TIME

Answer (score 0):

solved one column Name was missing(" " ) this symbols .thanks everyone